# Big difference in execution time for first and subsequent run of cupy functions

Tags: cupy

When I run cupy functions on cupy arrays, the first call of a function takes significantly longer than the second run, even if I run it on a different array the second time.

Why is this?

```py
import cupy as cp
cp.__version__
# 7.5.0

A = cp.random.random((1024, 1024))
B = cp.random.random((1024, 1024))

from time import time
def test(func, *args):
    t = time()
    func(*args)
    print("{}".format(round(time() - t, 4)))
    
test(cp.fft.fft2, A)
test(cp.fft.fft2, B)
# 0.129
# 0.001
test(cp.matmul, A, A.T)
test(cp.matmul, B, B.T)
# 0.171
# 0.0
test(cp.linalg.inv, A)
test(cp.linalg.inv, B)
# 0.259
# 0.002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CuPy is just-in-time compiling the kernel under the hood the first time you use a function in a Python process, which takes a bit of time.

From the CuPy [documentation](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/overview.html):

> CuPy uses on-the-fly kernel synthesis: when a kernel call is required,
> it compiles a kernel code optimized for the shapes and dtypes of given
> arguments, sends it to the GPU device, and executes the kernel. The
> compiled code is cached to $(HOME)/.cupy/kernel_cache directory (this
> cache path can be overwritten by setting the CUPY_CACHE_DIR
> environment variable). It may make things slower at the first kernel
> call, though this slow down will be resolved at the second execution.
> CuPy also caches the kernel code sent to GPU device within the
> process, which reduces the kernel transfer time on further calls.

Answer (score 0):

As per `cupy` [user guide](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/performance.html):

> **Context Initialization:**
> It may take several seconds when calling a
> CuPy function for the first time in a process. This is because the
> CUDA driver creates a CUDA context during the first CUDA API call in
> CUDA applications.